# AWS S3 presigned URL with metadata

Tags: django, python-2.7, boto3

I am trying to create presigned-url using boto3 below

```
s3 = boto3.client(
    's3', 
    aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY, 
    aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_ACCESS_SECRET, 
    region_name=settings.AWS_SES_REGION_NAME,
    config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
)
metadata = {
    'test':'testing'
}
presigned_url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
ClientMethod='put_object', 
Params={
    'Bucket': settings.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME,
    'Key': str(new_file.uuid),
    'ContentDisposition': 'inline',
    'Metadata': metadata
})
```

So, after the URL is generated and I try to upload it to S3 using Ajax it gives 403 forbidden. If I remove Metadata and ContentDisposition while creating URL it gets uploaded successfully.

Boto3 version: 1.9.33

Below is the doc that I referring to:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_url

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes I got it working,
Basically after the signed URL is generated I need to send all the metadata and Content-Dispostion in header along with the signed URL.
For eg: My metadata dictionary is {'test':'test'} then I need to send this metadata in header i.e. **x-amz-meta-test** along with its value and **content-dispostion** to AWS

Comment: Does this mean, you need to add it in "Params" while generation pre-signed URL, as well as send it in headers by the client who is uploading file using this pre-signed URL?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you'll get an error when trying to submit to the presigned URL, because the headers are different.

Comment: I am getting "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method".  Can you pls provide example code? Thx

Comment: I see what you mean but why would we have to include the "x-amz-meta-xyz" again?

Answer (score 5):

I found the metadata object needs to be key/value pairs, with the value as a **string** (example is Nodejs lambda):

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const { key, type, metadata } = JSON.parse(event.body);

    // example
    /*metadata: {
      foo: 'bar',
      x: '123',
      y: '22.4213213'
    }*/

    return await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', {
        Bucket: 'the-product-uploads',
        Key: key,
        Expires: 300,
        ContentType: type,
        Metadata: metadata
    });
};
```

Then in your request headers you need to add each k/v explicitly:

```
await fetch(signedUrl, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": fileData.type,
        "x-amz-meta-foo": "bar",
        "x-amz-meta-x": x.toString(),
        "x-amz-meta-y": y.toString()
      },
      body: fileBuffer
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

I was using `createPresignedPost` and for me I got this working by adding the metadata I wanted to the `Fields` param like so :-

```
const params = {
    Expires: 60,
    Bucket: process.env.fileStorageName,
    Conditions: [['content-length-range', 1, 1000000000]], // 1GB
    Fields: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        key: strippedName,
        'x-amz-meta-pdf-type': pdfType,
        'x-amz-meta-pdf-id': pdfId,
    },
};
```

As long as you pass the data you want, in the file's metadata, to the lambda that you're using to create the `preSignedPost` response then the above will work. Hopefully will help someone else...

Answer (score 2):

In boto, you should provide the `Metadata` parameter passing the dict of your key, value metadata. You don't need to name the key as `x-amz-meta` as apparently boto is doing it for you now.

Also, I didn't have to pass the metadata again when uploading to the pre-signed URL:

```
params = {'Bucket': bucket_name, 
          'Key': object_key, 
          'Metadata': {'test-key': value}
         }

response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('put_object',
                                             Params=params,
                                             ExpiresIn=3600)
```

I'm using a similar code in a lambda function behind an API